# Why does BeautifulSoup's unwrap method delete the text inside the tag instead of deleting the tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

From the [documentation on Beautiful Soup 4's `unwrap` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap), I expected the code below to print `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`. Instead, it prints `<p></p>`. Isn't `unwrap()` supposed to "replace a tag with whatever's inside that tag" (to quote the documentation)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import bs4
markup = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
p_tag = soup.p
p_tag.unwrap()
print(p_tag)
```

I think I'm misunderstanding the example in the documentation. I'm using Python 3.7.3 and Beautiful Soup 4.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is saying:

> Tag.unwrap() is the opposite of wrap(). It replaces a tag with
>   whatever’s inside that tag.

So it replaces the tag *inside the soup* with the content that is inside the tag.

Consider this example:

```
import bs4
markup = '<other_tag><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></other_tag>'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
p_tag = soup.p

print(p_tag.parent)     # <other_tag><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></other_tag>
p_tag.unwrap()
print(p_tag)            # <p></p>
print(p_tag.parent)     # None

print(soup.other_tag)   # <other_tag>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</other_tag>
```

With `.unwrap()`, we effectively remove the tag from the soup, and we replace this with content that was inside this tag. The unwrapped tag has now parent set to `None` and is empty -> it's content was moved elsewhere (to parent).